# Move from a Single Instance to a Load Balanced configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

we currently have a site that is on AWS ElasticBeanstalk as a Single Instance in production, but we would like to change that to Load Balanced.

The site currently uses .ebextensions to run a few things, and also set up the SSL from LetsEncrypt. Apart from that, it's a pretty bog-standard Magento site.

So, what would be the best way to switch without causing any downtime, and keeping the site available with HTTPS?

I am assuming it isn't as simple as changing it from a Single Instance to Load Balanced in Configuration -> Modify capacity, and setting it to, say, 1:5 for instances availabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it really is that easy. However, there will be a small amount of downtime.

Create an SSL certificate in Certificate Manager. This will be used for the load balancer.

Then switch the configuration in the AWS Console to add load balancing and setup the auto scaling launch configuration.

The reconfiguration will take about two minutes (in my experience).

Comment: Thanks, @john-hanley. Some, probably, simple questions: 1) How will the load balancer know to use the certificate I have created in Certificate Manager, Amazon magic? 2) Our domain's A record is currently pointing to the Amazon EB environment URL (abc.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com), I assume that will still be the entry point since the load balancer will auto-magically map to that? 3) If things go awry after creating the certificate/changing the config, can we simply opt to go back to the Single Server mode without any problems (other than a minute or two of downtime)?

Comment: 1) When you add the load balancer in the Beanstalk Console, you will select the certificate to use if you have (defined) an HTTPS listener. 2) The dns name won't change when you add a load balancer. 3) Yes, you just just change the configuration back (remove the load balancer, ...) and Beanstalk will automatically scale back. You can also save your environment first. Beanstalk is fairly bullet proof in my experience.

Comment: Ah, so the steps should be 1) create the SSL cert via Certificate Manager, 2) create the load balancer via EC2>Load Balancers>Create Load Balancer, 3) Head to EB and change to a Load Balanced config? If so, would step 2 interfere with the site before moving onto step 3?

Comment: No exactly. Step 1 is correct. The load balancer etc is created and configured by Beanstalk in the Beanstalk console. You do NOT create the load balancer outside of Beanstalk.

Comment: Thanks, @john-hanley, I thought that would probably be the case. However, when I select Load Balanced from the select menu I don't see any SSL options? I assume that means EB will have created the Load Balancer, but I then need to go into EC2>Load Balancers and set it to accept requests on 443 and change the SSL cert? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see there is also a Load Balancer section in the EB>Configuration screen. That answers that question, thank you!